# Replace multiple lines in HTML file which is marked by a start and end pattern.

Tags: regex, perl, build-automation

I'm trying to make an automated build and use Perl in it to update some paths in a file.

Specifically, in an html file, I want to take the block shown below

```html
<!-- BEGIN: -->
<script src="js/a.js"></script>
<script src="js/b.js"></script>
<script src="js/c.js"></script>
<!-- END: -->
```

and replace it with

```html
<script src="js/all.js"></script>
```

I have tried a few regexes like:

```
perl -i -pe  's/<--BEGIN:(.|\n|\r)*:END-->/stuff/g' file.html
```

or just starting with:

```
perl -i -pe  's/BEGIN:(.|\n|\r)*/stuff/g' file.html
```

But I can't seem to get past the first line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -i -pe 's/<--BEGIN:(.|\n|\r)*:END-->/stuff/g' file.html
```

This is so close.

- Now just match with the `/s` modifier, this allows `.` to match any char, including newlines.
- Most importantly, you want to start the match with `<!--`, note the `!`.
- Also, you want a non-greedy match like `.*?`, in case you have multiple `END` markers.
- Your example input shows that there may be extra spaces.

This would lead to the following substitution:

```
s/<!--\s*BEGIN:.*?END:\s*-->/stuff/sg
```

---

As [@plusplus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89093/plusplus) pointed out, the `-p` iterates over each line. Let's change Perl's concept of a “line” to “the whole file at once”:

```
BEGIN { $/ = undef }
```

or use the `-0` command line switch, without a numeric argument.

Comment: does that work for you? perl -p is running over the file line by line (`while (<>)` etc) so it seems unlikely to match like this...?

Comment: Thanks! The above regex works beautifully if I put all the above html on one line - all the text is replaced with "stuff". If I separate the html into multi lines, it fails to match. I also tried removing the "-p". Hmmm now I remember why I do my utmost to avoid regex :)

Comment: see the edit above - amon's original post was untested and didn't work.

Comment: Oow sounds fun so would this look something like: <code>perl -i -e 'BEGIN { $/ = undef } s/<!--\s*BEGIN:.*?END:\s*-->/stuff/sg' file.html</code> must confess I haven't touched Perl in ages.

Comment: `perl -0 -i -pe 's/<!--\s*BEGIN:.*?END:\s*-->/stuff/sg' file.html` (PS - it's backticks to highlight as code in comments)